# Multiple variables with the same name in POST request

Tags: post

I was working on a webbot and I came across this strange page where multiple variables had the same name but different values in as shown by the Firefox web console. I am not sure as to how I can replicate this behavior in python. Currently, I am using the requests library to make post requests and that takes in a dictionary of name and value pairs. And of course, dictionaries have unique keys. So I was wondering if anyone could tell me how to send post requests with multiple variables carrying the same name.

```
sel_subj:dummy
sel_subj:ECE
```

Thanks,
Rajiv

Edit: Here is the html source that causes this

```
<input type="hidden" value="dummy" name="rsts"></input>
<input type="hidden" value="dummy" name="crn"></input><br></br>
<input type="hidden" value="120138" name="term_in"></input>

**<input type="hidden" value="dummy" name="sel_subj"></input>**

<input type="hidden" value="dummy" name="sel_day"></input>
<input type="hidden" value="dummy" name="sel_schd"></input>
<input type="hidden" value="dummy" name="sel_insm"></input>
<input type="hidden" value="dummy" name="sel_camp"></input>
<input type="hidden" value="dummy" name="sel_levl"></input>
<input type="hidden" value="dummy" name="sel_sess"></input>
<input type="hidden" value="dummy" name="sel_instr"></input>
<input type="hidden" value="dummy" name="sel_ptrm"></input>
<input type="hidden" value="dummy" name="sel_attr"></input>
<table class="dataentrytable" summary="Table is used to present the course search criteria">     
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="delabel" scope="row"> … </td>
            <td class="dedefault" colspan="37">

                **<select id="subj_id" multiple="" size="10" name="sel_subj"> … 
                </select>**

             </td>
         </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

Notice how the select tag and the highlighted input tag have the same name.

Comment: Curious question! How can the website tell the different variables apart? If you did a `$_POST['name']` access, you could presumably only get one of these? Do you know how it's done by the site you are looking at?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to the websites source. I found this astounding at first too, but them I have noticed many instances throughout the website where firefox posts multiple variables with the same name and where I can confidently say that the website uses the values of all those variables. There must be some way indeed. I might try setting up a dummy website to see how this works.

Answer (score 1):

The only method that I know is using a variable-name appended with [].

```
<input type="hidden" value="dummy" name="sel_subj[]"></input>
<input type="hidden" value="ECE" name="sel_subj[]"></input>
```

This results in an array placed in `$_POST['sel_subj']`, with `$_POST['sel_subj'][0]` being "dummy" and `$_POST['sel_subj']` being ECE.

Now as I think of it, I think the creation of the array is done by the php-parser when there is a [] attached. This suggests that both values are send through the POST even if there is not [] at the end of the name. Maybe PHP can be configured not to dismiss this values.

Answer (score 1):

In case of GET variables (in the url), you can have multiple values with the same name. You can just parse the entire url and read and use every value.

PHP even solves this automatically if you add `[]` to the name of the parameter. In that case, it automatically changes it into an array. But this is a trick as well. It is fairly easy to write a piece of code that does the same thing with duplicate names without them having `[]` as a postfix.

They same will happen post variables as well. You just might need a little more code to read them properly.

The code in this case probably checks if there is `sel_subj` with any value other than `dummy`. If that is the case, then that value is used. If it doesn't exists, `sel_subj` may still exist with the value `dummy`. That is probably an indication for the script that the form was posted, but no value was selected.

So actually, I think it's quite easy to explain how this script works, and probably even why, but I don't think it's a very good solution to put all defaults in hidden fields this way, so I would suggest you don't try to replicate this solution. :-)